# How to select the "order" for the polynomial line for this type of graphy? (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[image: A graphy of calculation results]

I try to create the Polynomial trendline for this graphy in Excel 2013. I checked the infomation here:
[a link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Choosing-the-best-trendline-for-your-data-1bb3c9e7-0280-45b5-9ab0-d0c93161daa8)
They said 'Order 4 generally has up to three hills or valleys'. However, my graphy has more than 3 hills or valleys. I am not sure which order I should use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think order 6 should be ok as long as it shows the trend of your graph. Hope this helpful.